# How to use Visual Studio to deploy a trigger to multiple databases?

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, triggers

I have a trigger written in C# that is currently active on a production database. In order to test something things out, I want the trigger to be active on a test database as well. How do I make sure the trigger gets deployed to both the production and test databases?

As far as I can tell, the way the trigger gets deployed right now is:

- In Visual Studio, when I look at the properties of my code solution/project, there's a place for a database connection string. This string specifies the production database.
- When I go to Build -> Deploy Solution in Visual Studio, this deploys the trigger to the production database specified in the connection string.

So I guess another way of looking at the question is: is there some way of specifying multiple databases in the connection string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're using VS2010 database projects.  Rather than using Visual Studio to deploy  you could use the [VSDBCMD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193283.aspx) utility.  You can specify a connection string as a command line argument and then you could run the utility twice with different connection strings.

Another option would be to set up multiple project configurations in Visual Studio with a different connection string for each.

The [Visual Studio Database Guide](http://vsdatabaseguide.codeplex.com/) written by the Visual Studio ALM Rangers may be a useful resource.